# Grouping data with a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have some raw data like this:

```
Dear   John    Buy   1 of Coke, cost 10 dollars
       Ivan    Buy  20 of Milk
Dear   Tina    Buy  10 of Coke, cost 100 dollars
       Mary    Buy   5 of Milk
```

The rule of the data is:

- Not everyone will start with "Dear", while  if there is any, it must end with costs
- The item may not always normal words, it could be written without limits (including str, num, etc.)

I want to group the information, and I tried to use regex. That's what I tried before:

```python
for line in file.readlines():
    match = re.search(r'\s+(?P<name>\w+)\D*(?P<num>\d+)\sof\s(?P<item>\w+)(?:\D+)(?P<costs>\d*)',line)
    if match is not None:
        print(match.groups())
file.close()
```

Now the output looks like:

```
('John', '1', 'Coke', '10')
('Ivan', '20', 'Milk', '')
('Tina', '10', 'Coke', '100')
('Mary', '5', 'Milk', '')
```

Showing above is what I want. However, if the `item` is replaced by some strange string  like `A1~A10`, some of outputs will get wrong info:

```
('Ivan', '20', 'A1', '10')
('Mary', '5', 'A1', '10')
```

I think the constant format in the `item field` is that it will always end with `,` (if there is any). But I just don't know how to use the advantage.

Thought it's temporarily success by using the code above, I thought the `(?P<item>\w+)` has to be replaced like `(?P<item>.+)`.  If I do so, it'll take wrong string in the tuple like:

```
('John', '1', 'Coke, cost 10 dollars', '')
```

How could I read the data into the format I want by using the regex in Python?

Comment: Do you mean `Coke` can be `A1~A10`? Try using `(?P<item>[^,]+)`.

Comment: I suspect columns to be separated by tabs, could you confirm it?

Comment: Because fields could fill in different length of data, their space will not be fixed. I thought the `[^,]+` is a better idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried this regular expression

`^(Dear)?\s*(?P<name>\w*)\D*(?P<num>\d+)\sof\s(?P<drink>\w*)(,\D*(?P<cost>\d+)\D*)?`

Explanation

1. `^(Dear)?` match line starting either with `Dear` if exists
2. `(?P<name>\w*)` a name capture group to capture the name
3. `\D*` match any non-digit characters
4. `(?P<num>\d+)` named capture group to get the `num`.
5. `\sof\s` matching string `of`
6. `(?P<drink>\w*)` to get the drink
7. `(,\D*(?P<cost>\d+)\D*)?` this is an optional group to get the cost of the drink

with

```
>>> reobject = re.compile('^(Dear)?\s*(\w*)[\sa-zA-Z]*(\d+)\s*\w*\s*(\w*)(,[\sa-zA-Z]*(\d+)[\s\w]*)?')
```

First data snippet

```
>>> data1 = 'Dear   John    Buy   1 of Coke, cost 10 dollars'
>>> match_object = reobject.search(data1)
>>> print (match_object.group('name') , match_object.group('num'), match_object.group('drink'), match_object.group('cost'))
('John', '1', 'Coke', '10')
```

Second data snippet

```
>>> data2 = '       Ivan    Buy  20 of Milk'
>>> match_object = reobject.search(data2)
>>> print (match_object.group('name') , match_object.group('num'), match_object.group('drink'), match_object.group('cost'))
('Ivan', '20', 'Milk', None)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use this `regex`:

```
r'\s+(?P<name>\w+)\D*(?P<num>\d+)\sof\s(?P<item>[^,]+)(?:,\D+)?(?P<costs>\d+)?'
```

**Demo**

```
>>> line = 'Dear   Tina    Buy  10 of A1~A10'
>>> match = re.search(r'\s+(?P<name>\w+)\D*(?P<num>\d+)\sof\s(?P<item>[^,]+)(?:,\D+)?(?P<costs>\d+)?', line)
>>> match.groups()
('Tina', '10', 'A1~A10', None)

>>> line = 'Dear   Tina    Buy  10 of A1~A10, cost 100 dollars'
>>> match = re.search(r'\s+(?P<name>\w+)\D*(?P<num>\d+)\sof\s(?P<item>[^,]+)(?:,\D+)?(?P<costs>\d+)?', line)
>>> match.groups()
('Tina', '10', 'A1~A10', '100')
```

**Explanation**

The first section of your regex is perfectly fine, here’s the tricky part:

`(?P<item>[^,]+)` As we're sure that the string will contain a *comma*  when the *cost* string is present, here we say that we want *anything but comma* to set the item value.

`(?:,\D+)?(?P<costs>\d+)?` Here we're using two groups. The **important thing** is the `?` after the *parenthesis* enclosing the groups:

> '?' Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the
>   preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

So we use `?`  to match both possibilities (with the *cost* string present or not)

`(?:,\D+)` is a [non-capturing](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) that will match a comma followed by anything but a digit.

`(?P<costs>\d+)` will capture any digit in the named group *cost*.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Done ;) @SuperBiasedMan

Answer (score 5):

Without regex:

```
with open('commandes.txt') as f:
    results = []
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(None, 5)
        price = ''
        if parts[0] == 'Dear':
            tmp = parts[5].split(',', 1)
            for tok in tmp[1].split():
                if tok.isnumeric():
                    price = tok
                    break 
            results.append((parts[1], parts[3], tmp[0], price))
        else:
            results.append((parts[0], parts[2], parts[4].split(',')[0], price))
    print(results)
```

It doesn't care what characters are used except spaces until the product name, that's why each line is splitted by spaces in 5 parts. When the line starts with "Dear", the last part is separated by the comma to extract the product name and the price. Note that if the price is always at the same place (ie: after "cost"), you can avoid the innermost for loop and replace it with `price = tmp[1].split()[1]`

Note: if you want to prevent empty lines to be processed, you can change the first for loop to:

```
for line in (x for x in f if x.rstrip()):
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `.+`, the subpattern will grab the whole rest of the line as `.` matches any character but a newline without the `re.S` flag.

You can replace the `\w+` with a negated character class subpattern `[^,]+` to match one or more characters other than a comma:

```
r'\s+(?P<name>\w+)\D*(?P<num>\d+)\sof\s(?P<item>[^,]+)\D*(?P<costs>\d*)'
                                                ^^^^^
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/GNQjQ9):

```
import re
file = "Dear   John    Buy   1 of A1~A10, cost 10 dollars\n       Ivan    Buy  20 of Milk\nDear   Tina    Buy  10 of Coke, cost 100 dollars\n       Mary    Buy   5 of Milk"
for line in file.split("\n"):
    match = re.search(r'\s+(?P<name>\w+)\D*(?P<num>\d+)\sof\s(?P<item>[^,\W]+)\D*(?P<costs>\d*)',line)
    if match:
        print(match.groups())
```

Output:

```
('John', '1', 'A1~A10', '10')
('Ivan', '20', 'Mil', '')
('Tina', '10', 'Coke', '100')
('Mary', '5', 'Mil', '')
```